# Dynamically adding input fields and keeping track of what was entered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wanting to dynamically create input field values for each category a user creates, the issue is how can I keep track of what the user enters into the input field. As I cannot create X amount of states as it is dynamic. Any tips would be much appreciated, my code is shown below:

```
var categories = newData.map((category,index) => {
      console.log(category)
      return (
        <div className="content row marginCenter" key={category._id}>
          <p>{category.category}</p>
          <input type="text" /> //How do I keep track of what was entered for this input field??
          <button onClick={() => this.addCategoryLink(category._id)}>Add 
      link</button>
        </div>
      )
})
```

Comment: show us your data so its more clear what you want to do with that value

Comment: Hi, I'm wanting to track what the user types inside the <input /> field, and I am wondering how to bind that to the button element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering how to bind that to the button element

The React docs have a section related to the core of this question:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Assuming your state holds an array of "categories" objects- essentially, I think what you're looking for boils down to something like this in your map function:

```
{this.state.categories.map(category => (
  <input
    type="text"
    onChange={event => this.handleCategoryChange(category, event)}
    value={category.value}
  />
)}
```

And then a change handler that looks something like this:

```
handleCategoryChange = (category, event) => {
  const value = event.currentTarget.value;
  this.setState(state => {
    // Create a copy of the categories array:
    const categories = [...state.categories];

    // Create a copy of the category, with an updated value:
    categories[category.index] = {
      ...category,
      value
    };

    // Update state with the new values:
    return { categories };
  });
};
```

Here's a simple demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/woqpwvl777

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is good code but i think theres one problem if we end up implementing remove then category.index might remove the wrong items right?

Comment: This was just a quick example to show how you might manage dynamic state. If you wanted to be able to remove (or rearrange) categories within the array, you'd want to change the id/index mapping a bit, yes.

Answer (score 1):

i have other Way for doing this , Of course this way just working well in some situation , forExample when you have just 1 or 3 value

i think you wanna create Input , and there Input are dynamic , and you want define that , if user click in first Button , you get and use first TextInput (value)

in my way ( again i say this : this way just well in some situation ) , we Create data Json like this

```
[
  { id: n ,
    category: 'some',
    value: ''
   }
```

in this structure Value key , in the mounting contain nothing or null value if the Value not defined before

for now i create one handler method and this method, called after onChange Event fired on

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.getValue(category.id,e)} />
```

that element , this means when user start fill input onChange event handle function and update your state

```
 getValue(id,e) {

let thisId = id-1;
let vs = this.state.c;
vs[thisId].value = e.target.value;
this.setState({
  c:vs
});
let v = this.state.c[thisId];
console.log(v);
}
```

i create Pen in this address -> https://codepen.io/hamidrezanikoonia/pen/vRyJRx?editors=1111

you can check console , for more details ( open console tab in codepen )
and for more details , i create two method , the first fired when input (text) filled ( onChange event ) , and the other fired when clicked on button ( click event )